# Trouble Understanding the Recursion Here

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

Can someone please help to explain to me why this ends up in an infinite recursion loop?

The variable length reaches the value 1 but for some reason the loop is still entered even though the loops condition is while (length>1).

I've tried printing values and running it over and over again, maybe I'm missing something more obvious or someone can explain this more simply. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xMethod(5);
}

public static void xMethod(int length) { 
    while (length > 1) {
        System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");
        xMethod(length - 1);
    }
}
```

**Additional info.**

When I dubugged this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xMethod(5);
}

public static void xMethod(int length) { 
    while (length > 1) {
        System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");
        xMethod(length - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Coming out of while");
}
```

Below is the output :

```
4 3 2 1 Coming out of while
1 Coming out of while
1 Coming out of while
1 Coming out of while
1 Coming out of while
1 Coming out of while
1 Coming out of while
//repeated Infinite times
```

After coming out of `while` loop why it is going back in the same `while` loop with `length` as 2?

Edit: I appreciate all of your responses and understand that if I wanted to code something like this I would probably us an if statement as most recursive methods do but this is simply a question of me perhaps not understanding how the scope or call stack works. If I'm correct the while loop block holds on to the value of length as 2 no matter what happens outside of that block?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when i debugged the code in question i found that after while(1>1) condition it comes out of the loop and then again goes back to the while loop with while (2>1) how did that happen?

Comment: May we ask that you add a description of what this code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: The loop is infinite because length doesn't change within the loop. You probly don't need the loop if you use an if statement instead of while. The recursion is a replacement for the loop.

Comment: @bert That would seem to be the most sensible answer.  There shouldn't even be a loop there, because the recursion decrements the counter implicitly.

Comment: This is the actual question, it is not a matter of output as I thought the output would be 4,3,2,1 but I was wrong. Perhaps someone could explain the technical reason why does the value decrement to 1 and then change back to 2 when entering the loop?

Comment: @NicholasCorliss Because the loop doesn't end. You are again calling the method

Comment: Maybe it's easier for you to understand if you would assume, that you don't make a recursive call and call any other method with length - 1. The call returns and length stays as it is. You cannot change the length parameter of the calling method by calling the method with a different value recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing 2 things here. When you are writing a recursive code, you always need to think when the when code will end. Your code does not have a end case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
             xMethod(5);
}

public static void xMethod(int length) { 

     System.out.println("Method Start "+ length);
        while (length > 1) {

            System.out.println("Inside while "+ length);

             xMethod(length - 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Method End "+ length);                 
    }
}
```

Now this code produces the following output:

```
Method Start 5
Inside while 5
Method Start 4
Inside while 4
Method Start 3
Inside while 3
Method Start 2
Inside while 2
Method Start 1
Method End 1
Inside while 2
Method Start 1
Method End 1
Inside while 2
Method Start 1
Method End 1
Inside while 2
Method Start 1
Method End 1
.
.
```

As you can clearly see,

```
Inside while 2
Method Start 1
Method End 1
```

is repeated again and again.

So what this means is, when the length is 2, the following will happen.

```
while (2 > 1) {
     System.out.println("Inside while "+ length);
     xMethod(1);
}
```

The output for this is

```
Inside while 2
```

Now, `xMethod(1)` doesn't even enter the while loop, so this will be printed.

```
Method Start 1
Method End 1
```

But you should now understand that `while(2>1)` is again execute because the length has not changed and it is still `2`.

```
while (2 > 1){
    System.out.println("Inside while "+ length);
    xMethod(1);
}
```

goes on and the loop continues.

Comment: @NicholasCorliss Glad, you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not updating the value of length in the current method. The value is just decremented when sending to the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xMethod(5);
}

public static void xMethod(int length) {
    while (length > 1) {
        System.out.print((length) + " ");
        xMethod(length);
        length--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Functionally speaking, there is no difference between your answer and the code in the OP.  The OP's code is fine, running, and I think there is just some confusion about _why_ that code is working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the length is not decremented in the OP's question, hence the while loop runs in infinite loop.

Comment: `xMethod(length - 1)` <-- what do you think this is doing?  It is _decrementing_ the count, so that the next call in the recursive chain starts off with a length one smaller than the previous call.  This continues, until the length becomes zero.

Comment: @SandeshGupta it is same as OP question.

Comment: No @TimBiegeleisen, output of the present code is `5 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2..........`. But this code produces output as `4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 `.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The `length` is decremented in methods call, but the 'length' is not decremented for `while` loop

Comment: @SandeshGupta I get your point now...but I'm not sure what the OP actually wants to do here.  Maybe your solution would be acceptable, or maybe not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, the requirement is still unclear, but my answer explains why does it looping infinitely.

Comment: @SandeshGupta now your code is looping infinitely. `length--;` should be above not below. `xMethod(5)` is now continuously called

Comment: MaruthiAdithya Yes, you're correct. @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the edit

Comment: Surely ( length - 1) is a decrement so this is the main confusing part for me, perhaps it has something to do with the call stack?

Answer (score 2):

The variable length never reaches the value 1 in any loop, you mix two design and i think you need on of them, recursive method or loop.

first design:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xMethod(5);
}
public static void xMethod(int length) { 
    System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");
    if(length > 1)
        xMethod(length - 1);
    }
}
```

another way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xMethod(5);
}
public static void xMethod(int length) {
    while (length > 1) {
        System.out.print((length--) + " ");
    }
}
```

you can select one of these, it depend on your design.
if it's not your answer, please write your expect output.

Answer (score 0):

because when `length` reaches `2`  `xMethod(2)` is called and therefore `xMethod(1)` follows, when `xMethod(1)` ends, since `length` is still `2` it again calls `xMethod(2)` and the this calls `xMethod(1)` it repeates..

to fix it, use `return` after `xMethod(length - 1);`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        xMethod(5);
    }

    public static void xMethod(int length) { 

        while (length > 1) {

            System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");

             xMethod(length - 1);
             return;
        }
        System.out.println("Coming out of while");
    }
```